# pod in kubernetes can't establish the grpc connection

Tags: linux, kubernetes, tcp, grpc

My pod in kubernetes can't establish the grpc connection with other pod.
But It can establish the connection after I promote the permissions of POD to privileged. But I can't use privileged pod in production environment.

I add NET_BIND_SERVICE privilege to pod and it can do a little work, which privilege should I add either?
I also see the netstat in container,
[In the normal circumstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1DrZ.png),
[In the abnormal circumstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2dwD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open the grpc log, and found it's the container can't ping another container ipv6 address successfully.